# How to do tappable icons within iOS app that can be added or taken off by code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Well basically I am wondering how would I go about making icons within my app that I can manipulate (take out or put in) with my code? What tecniques should I be looking into?

Similar idea is presented in the "Flags" app where each flag is placed on a screen area and once user taps on specific flag it takes you to another screen and asks for input which is later cross checked with database.

I essentially want to do the same thing with my app but really have no understanding how would I go about making an area whith specific icons that can be tapped to make action i.e. take user to another screen.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose standard [UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) control is what you need, basic example of usage in view controller will be:

```
// ViewDidLoad:
UIButton* flagButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight)];
[tmpMainButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tmpMainButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someFlag.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:flagButton];

...

- (void) clickButton:(id)sender{
   // Display next controller here
   // e.g. if you use UINavigationController, then push it in navigation stack
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. This surely gives me some idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UIImageView` with your icon as its image and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it.

```
    //ViewDidLoad
    UIImageView *tempIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 100, 80, 80)] ;
    tempIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tutorial.png"];
    tempIcon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapForNextView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goToNextView:)];
    [tapForNextView setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapForNextView setDelegate:self];
    [tempIcon addGestureRecognizer:tapForNextView];
    [tapForNextView release];

    [self.view addSubview:tempIcon];

-(void)goToNextView:(id)sender
{
    //Code for showing next controller comes here 
}
```

You can also add  `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your icon to move it across the screen.
There's lot more you can do , just refer apple's documentation on  [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Comment: Thank you Nayan. I will look into these techniques as well.